# Spacing on rotatebox in tabular environment

Tags: tables, rotating

Could someone explain the spacing in this table?

- Why do some of the rotated boxes have 0, 1, 2, or 3 characters separated by the baseline?
- Why are there leading/trailing spaces in some of the boxes?

I don't understand what mechanisms control these things.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%

\newcommand{\testBox}[2]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fboxrule=.1pt%
  \fbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=#1]{#2}%
      {#1 #2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\tt

\begin{tabular}%
{@{}|llll|llll|llll|@{}}%
  \hline%
  \rlap{\rule{211pt}{.1pt}}%
  \testBox{rt}{090}&%
  \testBox{rb}{090}&%
  \testBox{rt}{270}&%
  \testBox{rb}{270}&%
  %
  \testBox{ct}{090}&%
  \testBox{cb}{090}&%
  \testBox{ct}{270}&%
  \testBox{cb}{270}&%
  %
  \testBox{lt}{090}&%
  \testBox{lb}{090}&%
  \testBox{lt}{270}&%
  \testBox{lb}{270}\\%
  \hline%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: rotateboxes-in-tabular]

Comment: It makes sense to me.  The designated coordinate, e.g., right-bottom, of the [original] box, remains at the same vertical position before and after rotation.  The only quirk is that if a rotated box would end up with a gap between the baseline and the box (as in, for example, right-top 270), the box is extended to the baseline, without relocation of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, it makes sense to me. The designated rotation origin, e.g., right-bottom, of the [original] box, remains at the same vertical position before and after rotation. The only quirk is that if a rotated box would end up with a gap between the baseline and the box (as in, for example, right-top 270), the box is extended to the baseline, without relocation of the text.

To show what I mean, I have adjusted your MWE somewhat to overlay the unrotated and rotated boxes, where the rotation point is overlapped in both pre- and post- image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%

\newcommand{\testBox}[3][0]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fboxrule=.1pt%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{#2 #3}}%
  \fbox{%
      {#2 #3}%
  }\kern-\wd0%
  \rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\wd0+#1\ht0][r]{\fbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=#2]{#3}%
      {#2 #3}%
  }}}%
  \kern\wd0%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\tt

  \leavevmode\rlap{\rule{211pt}{.1pt}}
  \testBox[1]{rt}{090}\quad
  \testBox{rb}{090}\quad
  \testBox{rt}{270}\quad
  \testBox[1]{rb}{270}

\renewcommand{\testBox}[3][0]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fboxrule=.1pt%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{#2 #3}}%
  \fbox{%
      {#2 #3}%
  }\kern-\wd0%
  \rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\wd0+#1\ht0][c]{\fbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=#2]{#3}%
      {#2 #3}%
  }}}%
  \kern\wd0%
}
  \leavevmode\rlap{\rule{211pt}{.1pt}}
  \testBox[1]{ct}{090}\quad
  \testBox[-1]{cb}{090}\quad
  \testBox[-1]{ct}{270}\quad
  \testBox[1]{cb}{270}

\renewcommand{\testBox}[3][0]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fboxrule=.1pt%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{#2 #3}}%
  \fbox{%
      {#2 #3}%
  }\kern-\dimexpr\wd0+#1\ht0\relax%
  \rlap{\makebox[\wd0][l]{\fbox{%
    \rotatebox[origin=#2]{#3}%
      {#2 #3}%
  }}}%
  \kern+\dimexpr\wd0+#1\ht0\relax%%
}
  \leavevmode\rlap{\rule{211pt}{.1pt}}
  \testBox{lt}{090}\quad
  \testBox[1]{lb}{090}\quad
  \testBox[1]{lt}{270}\quad
  \testBox{lb}{270}


\end{document}
```

[image]

For clarification, I manually added (outside of LaTeX) red marks at the origin of rotation.

[image]